# how to create sub page in laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am working in laravel 5.5 and I am trying to open page from route like

```
Route::get('/admin/admin/adminprofile', function() {   return \View::make('admin\adminprofile');});
```

but it is not working.
I am  trying to open Breadcrumbs pages.

Comment: Views shouldn't have slashes, they use dot notation.  Beyond that, what's the error?

Comment: @Devon how to use Breadcrumbs in laravel 5.5 ?

Comment: You're capitalizing "Breadcrumbs" like you're talking about some specific library. Are you talking about a particular tool for breadcrumbs, or just generally? If generally, you're responsible for writing your navigation HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::get('/admin/admin/adminprofile', function(){

    return view('admin.adminprofile', ['name' => 'James']);

});
```

[image]

**For More Details**  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views